# Ho do I check if all the rows in a particular column contain a specific string in Excel using VBA?

Tags: string, excel, vba

I have 2 columns of data in different sheets. We could call them A and B.B has a lot more rows of data than A and the data is also not the same. To be specific, in each data field there are some extra text appended at the end or in the beginning in B from A. I am trying to find out all possible rows in B which contain each row in A

Comment: For example 

Column A

Test a
Test b
Case 1 
Case 2

Column B

abcTest a
Test a 123
reTest am
123Case 2
Case 1 xyz
Case 235

What I expect:
Column A   Column B

Test a          abcTest a
                   Test a 123
                   reTest am
Test b
Case 1        Case 1 xyz
Case 2        123Case 2  
                      Case 235

Column A and B are in 2 different sheets.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple methods. It depends what you want to do.

Loop the rows.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
ws.Activate

lRow = 1

'Loop through and record what is in the first column
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

    If ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = "SomeValue" Then
        'Do something here
    End if

    lRow = lRow + 1
    ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
Loop
```

Or you can use find and findnext on a range. This will look for the value "2" in range a1:a500.

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500") 
    Set c = .Find(2, lookin:=xlValues) 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = c.Address 
        Do 
            c.Value = 5 
            Set c = .FindNext(c) 
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress 
    End If 
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question could benefit from further clarification. E.G. some example Data.

**What I think you're saying:**

A contains e.g.

```
"test1"
"test2" 
"test3"
```

B contains e.g.

```
"Test1-BData"
"Bdata2-Test3"
"Bdata3-Test1"
```

In this case. you need to define the length of the strings in A.

```
dim lngColumnAStringLength as long
    lngColumnAStringLength = 5

dim strTest as string
for I = '/start column B to '/ End column B
      strTest = left(columnBcell, X)
      strTest = right(columnBcell, X)
'/ Returns the first (or last) X characters of the string

      bMatchFound = false
      for j = '/ startcolumn A to end column A
           if strTest = (columnAcell.text) then bMAtchFound = true
      next j

if BMatchFound = true then '/ Copy to a 3rd list, hide row, whatever

next i
```

or, if your data is always appended with a delimiter e.g. "-" or "." or something like that. You can use

```
split(columnBtext, "-")
```

which, if B = "abc-def-ghij"
returns an array containing ("abc", "def", "ghij")